# Prove that a certain function defined by cases from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

**Question :** Prove that the $g:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ defined as :

$
    \begin{equation*}
g(x,y)=\begin{cases}
          2x+(2x+2y-1)(x+y-1) \quad &\text{ if } \, x \geq1 , y\geq1 \\
          2x+(x-y)(2x-2y-1) \quad &\text{ if } \, x \geq1 , y\leq0 \\
          1-2x+(y-x)(2y-2x-1) \quad &\text{ if } \, x \leq 0, y\geq1 \\
          1-2x-(1-2x-2y)(x+y) \quad &\text{ if } \, x \leq 0, y\leq0 \\
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
$

Is a bijection.

**My thinking:** To show that it is injective I think we have to consider the sixteen cases and show that in every case $x_1 = x_2 , y_1 = y_2$ if $g(x_1,y_1) = g(x_2,y_2)$ but the problem that I am not even able to prove a single case and for proving it a surjective I have no idea how to even start. Second approach I thought of was to find the inverse and then using the fact if the inverse exist then it is a bijection but both the approaches seen to very difficult for that monster looking definition of $g$.If someone has some good solution or even prooving even proof for single case in injectivity and one case in surjectivity will be great help.

**Edit 1:** If we prove that the function $k:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ defined as :

$
k(x,y) = x + \frac{(x+y-1)(x+y-2)}{2}
$

Is a bijection then above can prooved as it is a composition of $k$ and $h:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ defined as :

$
\begin{equation*}
h(x)=\begin{cases}
          2x \quad &\text{if} \, x \geq1 \\
          -2x+1 \quad &\text{if} \, x \leq0 \\
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
$

I hope to get a nice solution.

**Edit 2:** I have proved that it is a injection considering all 16 cases the only part left is for to prove it a surjection, I still dont know how will I find expressions for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g(m,n) = k$

Comment: If I were to define a bijection $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$, I'd count the points in a "spiral" around the origin. Such a function would be defined by a different fromula in each quadrant and it might be worthwhile to check if it coincides with yours. The picture might help finding a formal proof.

Comment: I tried it but it is only a informal argument for $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ to be countable I need it to be rigorous.

Comment: Yes. But it may help you in finding a formal proof. For surjectivity, you might want to find out in which quadrant and distance to the origin your preimage point lies. Your function $k$ might be some kind of "projection" of the spiral to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It may be helpful to look at the function in each quadrant along lines $\pm x \pm y = \text{const}$.

Comment: Note that on the anti-diagonal $x+y=n$, the values of $k(x,y)$ are all integers from $k(1,n-1)=\binom{n-1}{2}+1$ to $k(n-1,1)=(n-1)+\binom{n-1}{2}=\binom{n}{2}$, each occurring exactly once.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein thanks for helping